# Codeigniter: How to return success/fail message to the user after submitting an ajax form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm starting to get the hang of Codeigniter, but apparently am missing something here.

I'm not sure how to return data to the user after an ajax form submission.
Here are the relevant bits of my code, with the question inside:

**View:**

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?"))
    {
        var form_data = $('form').serialize();

        $.post("<?php echo site_url();?>" + "/products/update_multiple", (form_data),
// this is what I don't understand: how to populate the variable result with data returned from the model/controller?
           function(result) {
                    $('#myDiv').html(result);
            }
            )
    }
```

**Controller**:

```
function update_multiple()
{

 $this->load->model('products_model');
 $this->products_model->updateMultiple();
// What goes here, to grab data from the model and send it back to the ajax caller?
}
```

**Model**:

```
function updateMultiple()
{
// I have a drop down list to select the field to update. The values of the drop down list look like this: "TableName-FieldName". Hence the explode.

    $table_field = explode("-",$this->input->post('field'));
    $table = $table_field[0];
    $field = $table_field[1];

    $data = $this->input->post('data');

    $rows = explode("\n", $data);

    foreach($rows as $key => $row)
    {
        $values = explode(" ", $row);
        $arr[$key]["code"] = $values[0];
        $arr[$key][$field] = $values[1];
    }


   if ($this->db->update_batch($table, $arr, 'code'))
   {
       // Here is the problem. What should I return here, so that it would be sent back to the calling ajax, to populate the result variable?
   }

}
```

Comment: just echo "success" at end of your controller method and you will get way to handle this

Comment: read this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-codeigniter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return json

```
   if ($this->db->update_batch($table, $arr, 'code'))
  {
   print json_encode(array("status"=>"success","message"=>"Your message here"));
  }
```

jQuery inside your confirm function

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo site_url();?>" + "/products/update_multiple",
data:  $('form').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(content) {
    if (content.status == "success") {
       $('#myDiv').html(content.message);
    } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: why not to use proper HTTP code, like 200 for success ? List of all codes is available for example on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: Is it really relevant? If the function succeeds that's all that really matters no? If it doesn't you can always return error with the message of WHY it failed with this way of doing it. HTTP codes won't give you why a query failed

Comment: **Please note** `Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.`

Comment: @rick are you sure? Each code has explanation. Besides, you can add your custom message too, can't you? the only difference is that you will not have to include status => 'success' and this ugly string comparison in javascript

Comment: @mkk that string comparision is unnecessary indeed. there is already a `fail()` in case of error messages.

Comment: Interesting on the deprecation, I'll have to read that. I use the success because I do my form validation server side rather than in jQuery so I can use the error/success for the validation parts.

Comment: @RickCalder here's the [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR). sucess or error will still work but in future, it may cause a lot of headaches.

Comment: Thnax, @RickCalder. But shouldn't there be something in the controller that gets the json from the model and pass it to the view? I thought that's the way MVC works: everything goes to the controller, from there to the model, than back to the controller, and back to the view again.
Anyway, using your code above results with the error: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'content.status') - So I assume the json wasn't passed back to the view.

Comment: No the json doesn't need to come from the model, you're technically getting success or failure from the model then using the controller to send the right message, so it's fine for MVC. If you're using Chrome you can use the dev inspector to see what's happening in the background. Open the inspector with F12 and go to the Network tab, then on the bottom right click XHR there you can see the requests and responses you're getting. That's how I trouble shoot ajax.

Comment: @RickCalder, thanx for the pointer re dev inspector.
It still didn't work for me, so I took the print json line outside of the if statement, and voila, my div was updated. So it seems that even though the db was updated correctly, batch_update doesn't return true upon success. Any idea what does it return, or how can I check for success/fail on batch_update?

Comment: hmm, no I've never used it to be honest. I tend to send each update request on it's own, especially when using ajax. Are you sure all the updates were successful?

Comment: yes. all the updates were successful. I updated just 3 rows to make sure, and they were all updated.
I guess I could update each row separately, but it could be thousands of rows at once.  I assumed the performance would be better with batch_update.

Comment: Strange... sorry I have no answer for that one.

Comment: @itachi that was exactly my point about using http responses code. You cannot use fail() if you do not use them :)

Comment: @mkk actually you can use fail() even when not using them but you will need to set the status code in server side then on the conditionals.

Comment: @itachi what I mean by http response codes is exactly setting status code on server side, maybe I am not clear or I mixed some terms, but this is what I meant